# React - How to convert a simple function to a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, class, components

How do I convert this code into a class component? the problem is `const {value} = useDarkMode (false);` I don't understand how to apply it in a class component

```
import './Content.css'
import useDarkMode from 'use-dark-mode';

export default function Content () {

    const { value } = useDarkMode(false);

    return <div>
        <div className={value ? 'Dark_Mode' : 'Light_Mode'}>
            <h3>Hello from React.JS</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: `useDarkMode` is a hook and is a paradigm intended to be used along side functional components. You would have to extract the logic from within useDarkMode to a reusable pattern like HOCs or some other form of state management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
import './Content.css'
import React from 'react';
import useDarkMode from 'use-dark-mode';

export default function Content () {

    const { value } = useDarkMode(false);

    return <MyContent value={value} />
}

class MyContent extends React.component{
    render() {
        return <div>
            <div className={this.props.value ? 'Dark_Mode' : 'Light_Mode'}>
                <h3>Hello from React.JS</h3>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the MyContent class is in a different file? how can I reolyze it?

Comment: No problem. You can make MyContent class as a different file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hooks in class component. If you want to use `useDarkMode`, change your component class to functional component like this:

```
export const Content = () => {

    const { value } = useDarkMode(false);

    return (
      <div>
        <div className={value ? 'Dark_Mode' : 'Light_Mode'}>
            <h3>Hello from React.JS</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```